# Почему шрифт применяется только к цифрам?

Tags: html, css, шрифты

В дизайне есть шрифт Riffic, я выгрузил, подключил. Но он применяется только к цифрам, на буквы вообще не реагирует, это какая-то особенность шрифта? подключать пробывал уже по разному, никак, может кто сталкивался с такой проблеммой, уже несколько дней пытаюсь подключить

Comment: Вероятно, в нем нет русских букв если речь про них

Comment: Зачем задавать вопрос на миллионе платформ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данный шрифт поддерживает только вот эти языки:

```
Албанский
Английский
Африкаанс
Баскский
Бретонский
Букмол
Волапюк
Галисийский
Датский
Зулу
Индонезийский
Ирландский
Исландский
Испанский
Итальянский
Кечуанский
Корнский
Люксембургский
Малагасийский
Мэнский
Немецкий
Нидерландский
Новонорвежский
Оромо
Португальский
Романшский
Руанда
Рунди
Санго
Северный ндебеле
Сомалийский
Суахили
Узбекский
Фарерский
Финский
Французский
Шведский
Шона
Шотландский
Эстонский
```

Если у Вас текст на русском, то этот шрифт Вы не сможете к нему применить. Ищите русскоязычные шрифты. Есть похожие на riffic русскоязычные шрифты

Comment: Позвольте узнать источник информации. А лучше, укажите его в ответе.

Comment: https://fonts-online.ru/fonts/riffic-free